# Multithreading in C# and ConcurrentDictionary: Is the following usage correct?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dictionary, task-parallel-library

I have such a scenario at hand (using C#): I need to use a parallel "foreach" on a list of objects: Each object in this list is working like a data source, which is generating series of binary vector patterns (like "0010100110"). As each vector pattern is generated, I need to update the occurrence count of the current vector pattern on a shared ConcurrentDictionary. This ConcurrentDictionary acts like a histogram of specific binary patterns among ALL data sources. In a pseudo-code it should work like this:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<BinaryPattern,int> concDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<BinaryPattern,int>();
Parallel.Foreach(var dataSource in listOfDataSources)
{
     for(int i=0;i<dataSource.OperationCount;i++)
     {
          BinaryPattern pattern = dataSource.GeneratePattern(i);

          //Add the pattern to concDict if it does not exist, 
          //or increment the current value of it, in a thread-safe fashion among all
          //dataSource objects in parallel steps.
     }
}
```

I have read about TryAdd() and TryUpdate() methods of ConcurrentDictionary class in the documentation but I am not sure that I have clearly understood them. TryAdd() obtains an access to the Dictionary for the current thread and looks for the existence of a specific key, a binary pattern in this case, and then if it does not exist, it creates its entry, sets its value to 1 as it is the first occurence of this pattern. TryUpdate() gains acces to the dictionary for the current thread, looks whether the entry with the specified key has its current value equal to a "known" value, if it is so, updates it. By the way, TryGetValue() checks whether a key exits in the dictionary and returns the current value, if it does.

Now I think of the following usage and wonder if it is a correct implementation of a thread-safe population of the ConcurrentDictionary:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<BinaryPattern,int> concDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<BinaryPattern,int>();
Parallel.Foreach(var dataSource in listOfDataSources)
{
     for(int i=0;i<dataSource.OperationCount;i++)
     {
          BinaryPattern pattern = dataSource.GeneratePattern(i);

          while(true)
          {
             //Look whether the pattern is in dictionary currently,
             //if it is, get its current value.
             int currOccurenceOfPattern;
             bool isPatternInDict = concDict.TryGetValue(pattern,out currOccurenceOfPattern);

             //Not in dict, try to add.
             if(!isPatternInDict)
             {
                  //If the pattern is not added in the meanwhile, add it to the dict.
                  //If added, then exit from the while loop.
                  //If not added, then skip this step and try updating again.
                  if(TryAdd(pattern,1))
                        break;
             }
             //The pattern is already in the dictionary. 
             //Try to increment its current occurrence value instead.
             else
             {
                  //If the pattern's occurence value is not incremented by another thread
                  //in the meanwhile, update it. If this succeeds, then exit from the loop.
                  //If TryUpdate fails, then we see that the value has been updated
                  //by another thread in the meanwhile, we need to try our chances in the next
                  //step of the while loop.                   
                  int newValue = currOccurenceOfPattern + 1;
                  if(TryUpdate(pattern,newValue,currOccurenceOfPattern))
                       break;
             }

          }
     }
}
```

I tried to firmly summarize my logic in the above code snippet in the comments. From what I gather from the documentation, a thread-safe updating scheme can be coded in this fashion, given the atomic "TryXXX()" methods of the ConcurrentDictionary. Is this a correct approach to the problem? How can this be improved or corrected if it is not?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I am asking for a correct usage as well. This is not a straightforward code review question.

Comment: whenever you have a `while(true)`, you must make very certain that there is always a case in which the loop will eventually end.  it's hard to tell here, but it looks like there are conditions where this may loop forever.

Comment: Actually, a thread would loop in that 'while' as long as it fails to update the dictionary. In the worst case, it would never update it until all other threads finish their jobs and exit totally, then finally the current thread could gain opportunity to update the dictionary as it becomes the last thread still existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675(v=vs.110).aspx) method that encapsulates either add or update logic as single **thread-safe** operation:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<BinaryPattern,int> concDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<BinaryPattern,int>();
Parallel.Foreach(listOfDataSources, dataSource =>
{
    for(int i=0;i<dataSource.OperationCount;i++)
    {
        BinaryPattern pattern = dataSource.GeneratePattern(i);

        concDict.AddOrUpdate(
            pattern,
            _ => 1, // if pattern doesn't exist - add with value "1"
            (_, previous) => previous + 1 // if pattern exists - increment existing value
        );
    }
});
```

Please note that `AddOrUpdate`operation is not atomic, not sure if it's your requirement but if you need to know the exact iteration when a value was added to the dictionary you can keep your code (or extract it to kind of extension method)

You might also want to go through [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369.aspx)

Comment: Actually, AddOrUpdate is not atomic.  It's thread safe, but not atomic.  The same is true of GetOrAdd.  It's unfortunate that the documentation doesn't explicitly say "not atomic", but it implies it with this remark "If you call AddOrUpdate simultaneously on different threads, addValueFactory may be called multiple times, but its key/value pair might not be added to the dictionary for every call. "

Comment: This is a good choice, unless you need to know whether or not the value was actually added or not.  One of the unfortunate side-effects of AddOrUpdate is that it just throws away the value if it loses a race with another thread.  You can use this extension method to build a version of AddOrUpdate that tells you whether or not it succeeded.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/04/10264111.aspx

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, thanks, could be useful, but I don't think it's related to the question itself, though.

Comment: Well, It's related because it's unclear to me whether or not the application logic needs to know whether the add succeeded.  I think it does.  If that's the case, AddOrUpdate will generate inconsistent results, and thus will not be 100% equivalent to his original code.

Comment: In this particular case you can examine the return value of `AddOrUpdate`. If it's `1` then it was just added to the dictionary :)

Comment: Yes, but what if it's 15... you don't know if it was previously 12 and the value was thrown away or not.  In which case the REAL value should be 16.

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch Could you expand on the race you describe? Say two threads call [`AddOrUpdate`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,e5f450835d8600ed), both observe the key doesn't exist and race to add the same value. The thread that loses will *retry* (`TryAddInternal` returns false), read and update the value set by the first thread. I imagine I must be confused by your wording ("kvp might not be added/be thrown away, inconsistent results"); the generator shouldn't have any side-effects so the semantics are consistent to me.

Comment: @tne - You're not looking at it as a whole.  Notice that addValueFactory() is made before the call to TryAddInternal, and that no locking is done to prevent concurrent execution.  They both return their "newValue" and then they both call TryAddInternal.  One will succeed, one will fail.  The one that fails will try again, but it will also call addValueFactory() a second time, potentially resulting in a different "newValue", the first one was abandoned.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Thank you for indulging me. Yes indeed, and this is very much what one would expect; if it didn't generate a new value based on the one set by the thread that raced it, *then* we would observe inconsistencies wrt the semantics of `AddOrUpdate` (in this case two threads would arrive at the same result for the counter increment and we'd thus "miss a step"). I was very much alarmed by your statement that `AddOrUpdate` is not atomic, as it's really the whole point of it. If the factory is side-effect-free, do you have an example of what could go wrong for a counter such as this?

Comment: @tne - the "not atomic" means the entire operation is not atomic.  Not that the insert isn't.  Most people have the mistaken impression that two concurrent calls will be completely serialized.  They also won't expect that their delegate might get called multiple times for a single invocation.  The issue here is that if your delegate can product different results each time its called, you have a race condition.  You can also potentially get into a deadlock condition if both delegates have their own locking that is mutually exclusive.  There are just all kinds of gotchas and poss. side effects

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `BinaryPattern` is here, but I would probably address this in a different way.  Instead of copying value types around, inserting things into dictionaries, etc.. like this, I would probably be more inclined if performance was critical to simply place your instance counter in `BinaryPattern`.  Then use `InterlockedIncrement()` to increment the counter whenever the pattern was found.

Unless there is a reason to separate the count from the pattern, in which case the `ConccurentDictionary` is probably a good choice.

Comment: This is considerably faster.  Even if you need a (concurrent) dictionary to get the "canonical" counter, the number of concurrent updates of the hashtable will be much lower; and and interlocked inc is much cheaper.

Comment: The way I understand the question, you have several different, but equal instances of `BinaryPattern` and you want to count them. So instance counter won't help.

Comment: @svick - since we don't know what the code for "GeneratePattern" does, it's hard to know.. I see nothing in the question that indicates that multiple BinaryPattern instances are created, in fact that would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First, the question is a little confusing because it's not clear what you mean by `Parallel.Foreach`. I would naively expect this to be `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach()`, but that's not usable with the syntax you show here.

That said, assuming you actually mean something like `Parallel.ForEach(listOfDataSources, dataSource => { ... } )`…

Personally, unless you have some specific need to show intermediate results, I would not bother with `ConcurrentDictionary` here. Instead, I would let each concurrent operation generate its own dictionary of counts, and then merge the results at the end. Something like this:

```
var results = listOfDataSources.Select(dataSource =>
    Tuple.Create(dataSource, new Dictionary<BinaryPattern, int>())).ToList();

Parallel.ForEach(results, result =>
{
    for(int i = 0; i < result.Item1.OperationCount; i++)
    {
        BinaryPattern pattern = result.Item1.GeneratePattern(i);
        int count;

        result.Item2.TryGetValue(pattern, out count);
        result.Item2[pattern] = count + 1;
    }
});

var finalResult = new Dictionary<BinaryPattern, int>();

foreach (result in results)
{
    foreach (var kvp in result.Item2)
    {
        int count;

        finalResult.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out count);
        finalResult[kvp.Key] = count + kvp.Value;
    }
}
```

This approach would avoid contention between the worker threads (at least where the counts are concerned), potentially improving efficiency. The final aggregation operation should be very fast and can easily be handled in the single, original thread.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach()` has overloads (like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486)) that support this kind of pattern.